# How can I set the width of an image in img tag using percentages or em respective to a parent or body?

Tags: html, css

How can I set the width of an image in img tag using percentages or em respective to a parent or body?

Comment: What's wrong with the CSS?

Comment: Do you want it relative to the viewport? Google viewport units.

Comment: Trying width:60%; in CSS doesn't work for you?

Comment: no, whenever i add a 30% or something, it's setting 30% of the entire width of the image. what should i do to get 30% of it's parent's div or something like that?

Comment: does figure tag's width work differently than image inside it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 30% of its parent element, make sure you set the parent element's `position` to `relative`.

Comment: You must set the positioning of the parent element for many CSS rules to behave as you expect them to.

Comment: Can you show us your code, it makes no sense to keep guessing.

Comment: thanks, mate it worked. i didn't set absolute positioning for the child this time.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franvarn/QqRPz/)

You can do a wrap around the image that has a max-width. Then set the image's width to 100%.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="imgWrap">
        Image here
        <img src="img.png" />
    </div>
</div>

#imgWrap {
    max-width: 300px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: set it to something else??

Comment: Never mind, I'll delete the comments, my point was that you don't need two wrappers every time you want to do something like this, and that max-width is the same as width for the block elements, and that it won't work for absolute images... This works the same as your example with just basic elements: http://jsfiddle.net/QqRPz/4/, and you can even remove the div: http://jsfiddle.net/QqRPz/5/

Comment: i could of left off #wrap but OP said "...respective to parent or body" so i was going for a parent type example.

Answer (score -1):

Add `Position:relative` to the parent

**NOTE:** In HTML 4.01, the width could be defined in pixels or in % of the containing element. In HTML5, the value must be in pixels.